# how to apply js for all input type which are in form

Tags: php, jquery

i want to apply js for all form input, I tried with below js

```
$('input #guest-login-form-register-form_es_').keyboard();
```

But this is not working for me.how can i apply this js ?

Comment: Could you post your html ?

Comment: if  `guest-login-form-register-form_es_` is form id you can use it as context , like so `$('input', '#guest-login-form-register-form_es_').keyboard();`

Comment: How about `$('form :input').keyboard();` ?

Comment: I want to add js only that input which are under form id `#guest-login-form-register-form_es_`

Comment: You're asking to find input children with class `guest-login-form-register-form_es_`

Comment: #insanebits yes right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#guest-login-form-register-form_es_  input').keyboard();
```

will work.

The one that you are using selects form with id "#guest-login-form-register-form_es_" and is a child of input, Which is what you don't want.

Comment: @Nikul can you share your HTML... Make sure that the form has the same id. Also try to find the node without calling the keyboard function on it in the console..